# Only "Open With..." and "Send to" options when right clicking a file

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2003, file-server

Encountered a strange problem on a Windows Server 2003-based file server.
Some files when right-clicked have only two options: **Open with...** and **Send to**.

Other similar files in the same directory look and work okay and have way more contextual menu items when right-clicked on.

I'm trying to *robocopy* these files over to another place, but receive **Access Denied** errors when encountering these kinds of files.

I tried to take ownership recursively from under **Security** tab > **Advanced** > **Owner** tab of the *root folder* these files are in, and it goes through without throwing any errors at me, but that doesn't solve the issue. I also tried use **takeown** and **icals** command from CMD(ran as administrator) without success.

Anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: Did I read that correctly... *Server 2000*? No, that's not right. There was no "Run as Administrator" option in Server 2000.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator My mistake. I just checked and it's 2003.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it was the first result on my google search, so just in case somebody else stumbles upon this.

Windows only displays those two options if the path is too long. So either:
1. Make the path shorter.
2. Map the folder as a network drive, then you can modify them there.